# Wordpress Theme page routing

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In the dashboard I created a page with no content called **Submit** with a slug of '**submit**'.
I then added a page to my theme folder, copying the **page.php** file and calling it **page_submit.php**
I can access this page as evident by adding a string specific to this php file.  I get there via '**.../submit**'

I then add php code to process a form.  the form gets rendered but on submission, I get a 404 error that the page is not found.  It is trying to fine a page called submit which does not exist but page-submit.php DOES exist.

I don't fully understand the fall thru of file routing or what the issue is here.  I just need the form to submit.

TIA

Comment: are you passing other URL variables, specifically 'name'. They can interfere with how WordPress handles its internal rewrite.

Comment: The essence (although changed) of the script can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960114/wordpress-404-error-when-running-this-page

Comment: the test page can be seen at wp1.jeffserver.com/submit

Comment: I looked at your page and didn't see anything. Maybe a var_dump of the WordPress query_vars and the $_SERVER variables on your 404 page may shed some light on it.

Comment: The closest I got was to see the 404 in Firebug or equiv when the page is submitted.  What is it that causes the "page-" prefix to be added to the slug?